# how to fetch data of all collections from firebase in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch data from the firebase. I have two collections, and I want data from both collections to be printed. When I fetch, only data from one collection is shown

```
const fetchData = () => {
        const arr = []
        db.collection('storedata').get().then((querysnapshot) => {
            querysnapshot.forEach((element) => {
                const dataSet = element.data()
                if (email !== '' && password !== '') {
                    return arr.push(setInfo([dataSet]))
                }
            })
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching data from the collection 'storedata', using:

```js
db.collection('storedata').get()
```

If you want to do the same but with other collection you need to explicitly write the same code for whatever other collection you are trying to fetch!

To achieve what you want to achieve you need to know the name of the other collection and repeat the same process you made for 'storedata' collection

##### You can't, and should not try to fetch all documents in the Firestore database.

But if you absolutely need for it to happen, then it's better to make it explicit by fetching each collection one by one.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out, I finally got the answer. I made a useState and change it when data fetches. Thank you again..

Comment: But that doesn't seem to have anything to do with the original problem xD

Comment: I know I am sorry for that Lautaro. I meant I created a use state [info. setInfo], and my wrong step was to create an array named arr and push data into it. But I found another method which is fast and perfectly working on that. I stored all data in a variable and applied a map function to it. BTW thank you so much for helping me.